# Time Series Stata date convert daily to quarterly returns scientific notation

Tags: date, time-series, stata

I have data with daily frequency from 01Jan2000 to 30Dec2015, this series was formatted as date (format date %d). I was able to extract day, month and year using day(date), month(date), and year(date).

I also need to generate a variable indicating its quarter, I used gen quarterly=dofq(date), and then format quarterly %tq. Instead of returning the format 2000q1, I got bunches of scientific notations (eg. 1.2e+06). Does anyone know why and how I can fix that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Here is some sample code that may point you in the direction you seek.

```
. clear

. set obs 1
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 1

. generate test = td(21nov2016)

. format %d test

. generate qtr = quarter(test)

. generate yq = qofd(test)

. format %tq yq

. list

     +--------------------------+
     |      test   qtr       yq |
     |--------------------------|
  1. | 21nov2016     4   2016q4 |
     +--------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you William, this works perfectly. But I am confused why is it necessary to generate qtr as a middle step instead of generating yq directly?

Comment: If you run the code, omitting the `generate qtr` command, you will see that it is not necessary to generate `qtr` in order to generate `yq`. I included `generate qtr` because it seemed possible to me, given your prior generation of `year`, `month`, and `day`, that your ultimate goal was perhpas to use `yq` to generate `qtr`, and I wanted to demonstrate that `yq` is not needed for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

To build on what you have done so far: you should realize that the same way you extracted the variables `day`, `month`, and `year` from `date` you can extract the *quarter* (e.g., `gen quarter = quarter(date)` in your case). Then, using the variables `quarter` and `year` as input you can generate a new variable `gen year_quarter = yq(year,quarter)` and format it with `%tq`. Essentially, this is what the function `qofd()` (taken from William's example) does in the background without generating the additional variables `quarter` and `year`.